# Trouble with camera in Windows Phone 8.0 using videobrush

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, dispose

I got bug in my app and can not solve it.

Bug is - I can not use camera more than three times.

Code, that demonstrates it is here:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp1.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Devices;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        PhotoCamera aCamera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cam = new camera_VM();

        }
    }


    class camera_VM
    {
        public camera_VM()
        {
            VideoBrush __cameraView = new VideoBrush();
            PhotoCamera aCamera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
            __cameraView.SetSource(aCamera);            
        }
    }
}
```

On **third** launch - it throws error:

```
   {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.VideoBrush_SetExternalVideoPortSource(VideoBrush vb, String sPortName)
   at Microsoft.Devices.Camera
```

Have no idea - what does it mean.

My guess that having **Videobrush** in code - bad idea, but have I another option? I got Grid in DataTemplate, that binds to VideoBrush object.

If I must properly dispose camera unit - can anyone tell me, how to do it right?

P.S. Code is just example, that fires an error.

Comment: Rewrite with good old CameraCaptureTask. Works like a charm.